# Can't get document id properly Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding data to my Firestore like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference newItemRef = db.collection("users").document();
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Item newitemu = new Item();
newitemu.setName(name);
newitemu.setLink(link);
newitemu.setItem_id(newItemRef.getId());
newitemu.setUserId(userId);

newItemRef.set(newitemu).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            toastMessage("Created new item");
            toastMessage("The id is: "+newitemu.getItem_id());
        }
        else{
            toastMessage("Failed to create new item");

        }

    }
});
```

And it works, I can observe the added item on my Firestore database. And as you can see I set Item_id on my Item object. I can set it and get it properly.
Then in this code, I am trying to delete a document:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

DocumentReference newItemRef = db.collection("users").document();
idToBeDeleted = emp.getItem_id().toString();

db.collection("users").document(idToBeDeleted) //When I put document id manually it works
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Timber.d("Succesfully deleted item" + idToBeDeleted);
            }
        });
```

When I put document id manually it works and deletes it successfully. But when I store it in a variable (idToBeDeleted) it doesn't work. Why? I really don't understand

Edit:

```
   FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    idToBeDeleted = emp.getItem_id().toString();
                    DocumentReference newItemRef = db.collection("users").document(idToBeDeleted);
                    newItemRef
                            .delete()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Timber.d("Succesfully deleted item" + idToBeDeleted);
                                }
                            });
```

To Add Data:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                String newItemId = db.collection("users").document().getId();
                DocumentReference newItemRef = db.collection("users").document(newItemId);
                String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                Item newitemu = new Item();
                newitemu.setName(name);
                newitemu.setLink(link);
                newitemu.setItem_id(newItemId);
                newitemu.setUserId(userId);
```

[image]

Comment: What is `emp.getItem_id()`?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
DocumentReference newItemRef = db.collection("users").document();
```

It means that you are creating a reference to a document with a random ID. Calling [CollectionReferenc#document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) method, without passing any arguments:

> Returns a DocumentReference pointing to a new document with an auto-generated ID within this collection.

This means that you need to first generate the ID and then save it in your object like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
String newItemId = db.collection("users").document().getId(); //Generate it first
DocumentReference newItemRef = db.collection("users").document(newItemId);
//                                                               ☝️
Item newitemu = new Item();
newitemu.setName(name);
newitemu.setLink(link);
newitemu.setItem_id(newItemRef);
//                    ☝️
newitemu.setUserId(userId);

newItemRef.set(newitemu).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

To be able to delete the item, you have to create a reference that points to that document. Again, calling `.document()` when creating the reference isn't helpful, as it creates again a random document. So to solve this, you need to use the following code:

```
newItemRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not delete. I edited my question. is it correct?

Comment: The code where you are adding the data is correct. Where you seem to me it's not. And this is because idToBeDeleted does not contain the correct ID. What does `emp.getItem_id()` return? Most likely something else than `kLXT .. nZsw`, right?

Comment: İt should return the correct id but I can't check I cant print in the console using log.d it does not show up

Comment: Most likely you use the value of newItemRef before you actually set it in the object. If you hard code the value of the document, does the delete operation work?

Comment: Yeah hardcoding works without any problem

Comment: I can get emp.getName and emp.getLink properly so I assume that emp.getItem_id should return the correct value

Comment: It will return the correct value if it's properly set. Otherwise, it won't. Are you sure you are trying to delete the document right after is successfully set? This means you have to use nested listeners. For example, once the data is set, is available to be deleted. So most likely you are trying to delete a document that wasn't added, as it takes time to write data in the database.