# Can't add Firebase document Id to dataClass

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data class for data that come from user entries. İt is carrying this data to Firebase. This data class also includes documentId variable which is a empty string by default. I want to add document Id's that Firebase created automatically. I tried every way I could think of. But it takes default value in any way.

Here are the four code snippets about this issue. Data class, adding data activity, and retrieving data activity and their View Models.

Dataclass:

```
data class AnalyzeModel(
var concept: String?="",
var reason: String?="",
var result: String?="",
var rrRatio: Double?=0.0,
var tarih: Timestamp=Timestamp.now(),
var tradingViewUrl: String="",
var id : String="")
```

AddAnalyzeActivity, addData function:

```
    fun addData(view: View) {

    val tarih = com.google.firebase.Timestamp.now()
    val rr = rrText.text.toString()
    var doubleRR = rr.toDoubleOrNull()
    if (doubleRR == null) { doubleRR = 0.0 }

    val analyzeDTO = AnalyzeModel(
        conceptText.text.toString(),
        reasonForText.text.toString(),
        resultAddingText.text.toString(),
        doubleRR,
        tarih,
        chartImage.text.toString()
    )
    viewModel.save(analyzeDTO)

    val intent = Intent(this, PairDetailActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

AddAnalyze ViewModel, save function:

```
    fun save(data: AnalyzeModel) {

    database.collection(dbCollection!!).document("Specified").collection("Pairs")
        .document(chosenPair!!)
        .collection("Analysis")
        .add(data)
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            exception.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

PairViewModel, retrieveData function:

```
    private fun retrieveData() {

    val docRef = collectionRef.orderBy("tarih", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        try {
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty) {
                val allAnalysis= ArrayList<AnalyzeModel>()
                val documents = value.documents
                documents.forEach {
                    val analyze = it.toObject(AnalyzeModel::class.java)
                    if (analyze!=null){

                        allAnalysis.add(analyze)
                    }
                }

                list.value = allAnalysis
            } else if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Application(), error.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to add document IDs that Firebase created automatically.

To solve this, you only need to annotate the field with [@DocumentId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentId.html).

```
data class AnalyzeModel(
    var concept: String?="",
    var reason: String?="",
    var result: String?="",
    var rrRatio: Double?=0.0,
    var tarih: Timestamp=Timestamp.now(),
    var tradingViewUrl: String="",
    @DocumentId 
    var id : String=""
)
```

Be also sure to have the latest version of Firestore.

Comment: When i try this, id field does not even created. Also my recyclerView disappearing.

Comment: That's most likely isn't related to that annotation, right?

Comment: I added the annotation then created new Data and it was not containing id field. Also my recyclerView started to not showing the items.

Comment: Have you also tried to define like this `var id : String?=null`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: No, it does not make any difference. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: It should definitely work. Using an annotation, should not stop a RecyclerView from displaying the data. You might also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977581/cant-get-document-id-properly-firestore) out.

Comment: The link you mentioned seems like helpful for my situation but there is one question: firstly you are getting id with `document().getId()` then you are creating itemRef using the objected id before. But how to the firebase know which document being created with that id. The question may be weird with that way. I want to know what you did ? Is it creating the document that has an id before, then adding the item to it?

Comment: No, the document is created only when we use `set()`. When we call `.document().getId()` we only generate (reserve) the ID that will be used in the future to create the document.

Comment: Is it ok now? Can I help with other information?

Comment: Actually you can. It's a confusing point that I'm adding data using `addData` function I guess I have to add documentId in this part too **BUT** I can access the correct document Id only from `retrieveData` function(in `document.forEach()` method) e.g if I try to get document ids from `addData` function i can access all doc id's but not it is not  giving correct id (selected item's id) to me.  Therefore I can never access the selected document Id from anywhere and can't add it to my Model class. Some tutorials doing this operation in `retrieveData` but for mine, it does not work.

Comment: If I try to add id in `retrieveData` using `analyze.id= it.id` it returns default value in firebase. İt never ever take any id.

Comment: Without seeing the code that behaves that way, I cannot be much of a help. Most likely, you should consider asking a new question.

Comment: i asked a new question Could you take a look at it please ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72270595/adding-document-%c4%b0d-to-firebase-document-as-a-field)

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: in fact new question is related to initial issue. So ı think ı explained a bit better than here.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial issue?