# Adding document İD to firebase document as a field

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model with default values. My app gets the data from user through EditTexts and add them to Firebase Firestore. I hava an `addData` function (in `AddAnalyzeActivity`) and `save`function (in `AddAnalyzeViewModel`) for this operation. I'm getting EditText entries in `AddAnalyzeActivity` and adding them to my model **but** on this step ı want to add document id to my model but I can't access the documentIds properly in `AddAnalyzeActivity`. I can only access them with a forEach method when I try to retrieving the mentioned data with `retrieveData` function (in PairDetailVM) from Firestore but If I try to add document Ids in `retrieveData` method it only adds default value of documentId.

What I tried to:

1. Using `@DocumentId` annotation in my model.
2. Setting null default value of documentId in my model.
3. Getting a list of all documents' ids but can't match them with actual items.

Here is the screenShot for logic:

[image]

`AnalyzeModel`:

```
data class AnalyzeModel(
var concept: String?="",
var reason: String?="",
var result: String?="",
var rrRatio: Double?=0.0,
var tarih: Timestamp=Timestamp.now(),
var tradingViewUrl: String="",
var id : String="")
```

`addData` :

```
fun addData(view: View) {

    val tarih = com.google.firebase.Timestamp.now()
    val rr = rrText.text.toString()
    var doubleRR = rr.toDoubleOrNull()
    if (doubleRR == null) { doubleRR = 0.0 }

    val analyzeDTO = AnalyzeModel(
        conceptText.text.toString(),
        reasonForText.text.toString(),
        resultAddingText.text.toString(),
        doubleRR,
        tarih,
        chartImage.text.toString()
    )
    viewModel.save(analyzeDTO)

    val intent = Intent(this, PairDetailActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

`save` :

```
    fun save(data: AnalyzeModel) {

    database.collection(dbCollection!!).document("Specified").collection("Pairs")
        .document(chosenPair!!)
        .collection("Analysis")
        .add(data)
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            exception.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

`retrieveData`:

```
    private fun retrieveData() {

    val docRef = collectionRef.orderBy("tarih", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    docRef.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        try {
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty) {
                val allAnalysis= ArrayList<AnalyzeModel>()
                val documents = value.documents
                documents.forEach {
                    val analyze = it.toObject(AnalyzeModel::class.java)
                    if (analyze!=null){

                        allAnalysis.add(analyze)
                    }
                }

                list.value = allAnalysis
            } else if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Application(), error.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the document ID into the document itself, consider separating the creation of the new `DocumentReference` from writing to it, by using `set` instead of `add`.

```
fun save(data: AnalyzeModel) {

    val newRef = database.collection(dbCollection!!).document("Specified").collection("Pairs")
        .document(chosenPair!!)
        .collection("Analysis")
        .document()     //  generates a new reference with a unique ID

    data.id = newRef.id //  set the ID into your object

    newRef.set(data)    //  writes the data to the new reference
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            exception.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

Also see the second snippet in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#kotlin+ktx_7)